# The numerical evaluations of special values of $L$-functions associated to modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, na.numerical-analysis

[LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/) has a database of lots of classical modular forms. Suppose we have a modular form $f$ listed in LMFDB, which usually gives the first 100 terms of the $q$-expansion. Are there any packages/programs that can compute the special values of the $L$-function $L(f,s)$ to a high precision. For example, compute the first 100 digits of the special value $L(f,s=2)$!

Comment: This is possible in Pari/GP and Magma, see the respective documentations.

Comment: Sage can do this too. I believe all three packages use the same algorithms, which are due to Tim Dokchitser -- see his paper "Computing special values of motivic L-functions", https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.em/1090350929

Comment: Yes, the starting point was TIm Dokchitser's algorithm, initially implemented in Pari/GP and now an improved version in Magma. The recent version of Pari/GP also has improved algorithms using ideas of Pascal Molin, and can be combined with the new modular forms package.

Comment: You may also find the following course of Henri Cohen useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10904